# probability question(defective items )

Tags: probability

There are 15 CD's out of which 4 are defective . CD's are selected one by one without replacement(10 times). What is the probability that the  last defective ball is chosen at the 10th time?

I have used the following approach

First fix one defective CD for the 10 th choose and fix the 1st , 2nd ,3rd choose for defective CD's ,

Now the probability of this can be chosen by (4/15)*(3/14)*(2/13)*(11/12)*(10/11)*(9/10)*(8/9)*(7/8)*(6/7)*(1/6)==P(say)...

Now the first 3 defective items can be arranged in (C(9,3) ways and each defective items can go to 10 th place at a time(4 ways) ...

So the required probability is P*C(9,3)*4...

But the Answer is not correct !!!

Comment: I have used the following approach    First fix one defective CD for the 10 th choose and fix the 1st , 2nd ,3rd choose for defective CD's , Now the probability of this can be chosen by (4/15)*(3/14)*(2/13)*(11/12)*(10/11)*(9/10)*(8/9)*(7/8)*(6/7)*(1/6)==P(say)...Now the first 3 defective items can be arranged in (C(9,3) ways and each defective items can go to 10 th place at a time(4 ways) ...So the required probability is P*C(9,3)*4... But the Answer is not correct !!!

Comment: Is this the probability the $10$th CD/ball selected is defective, or the probability that the five unselected CDs/balls are not defective and the $10$th CD/ball selected is defective?

Comment: @henry the question states that the 10 th pick should choose last defective CD that means between remaining picks , 3 other defective CD's are already chosen

Comment: @Bram28  I have done as per my capability

Comment: Do you get a hint by looking at your answer, and the correct one ?

Comment: @vikashtiwari Very good; we always appreciate seeing some effort! And, that way we can pinpoint specific issues with your approach.

Comment: @Bram28   Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

A simple way is to imagine all the CDs in a row, and see that if the $4^{th}$ defective is in the ${10}^{th}$ position, the other three must be among the first $9$, so $Pr = \dfrac{\binom93}{\binom{15}4}$

The approach you started with can also lead to the correct answer, now try to figure out what needs to be corrected, and why...